# How to store BigDecimal in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am trying to store BigDecimal in Firebase:

```
data class Money(val amount: BigDecimal = BigDecimal.ZERO, val currency: Currency = Currency.USD)
```

But when pushing data to database, getting an exception:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to parse node with class class java.math.BigDecimal
                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpf.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpf.zzar(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpf.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpf.zzar(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpf.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown Source)
```

How can I store it?

Comment: You will have to store it as a String and then serialize/deserialize it as needed.

Comment: I am doing it now, but I think must be more nice way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a following delegate:

```
class BigDecimalConverterDelegate(val bigDecimalProperty: KMutableProperty<BigDecimal>) {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): String {
        return bigDecimalProperty.getter.call().toString()
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: String) {
        bigDecimalProperty.setter.call(BigDecimal(value))
    }
}
```

Then you have to create two properties:

```
data class Money(
    @get:Exclude @set:Exclude var bigDecimalAmount: BigDecimal = BigDecimal.ZERO
) {
    var amount: String by BigDecimalConverterDelegate(this::bigDecimalAmount)
}
```

First `BigDecimal` property is annotated with `@get:Exclude` and `@set:Exclude` so it will be ignored by Firebase during serialization/deserialization.

The `String` property uses the delegate defined above. It doesn't have a backing field so Firebase will use `String getAmount()` and `setAmount(String amount)` methods while serializing/deserializing this class. These calls will be delegated to the `BigDecimalConverterDelegate` which will set or get the value directly from the `BigDecimal` property.

Please note that you also have to include the `kotlin-reflect` lib:

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
```

### Issue with kotlin-noarg

Unfortunately delegates don't work if you would want to use them with "kotlin-noarg" plugin (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16692). The empty constructor is totally empty and delegates are not initialized there:

```
public Money(@NotNull BigDecimal bigDecimalAmount) {
  Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(bigDecimalAmount, "bigDecimalAmount");
  super();
  this.bigDecimalAmount = bigDecimalAmount;
  this.amount$delegate = new BigDecimalConverterDelegate((KMutableProperty)(new Money$amount$2(this)));
}

public Money() {
}
```